# Clarifying time complexity for a specific algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, list, performance, time-complexity

Consider I have done popping an arbitrary element from a list of n/2 elements n/2 times.Will the time overall time complexity be O(n2) or O(n)

Answer (score 0):

if you are popping an element whose index is unknown in your list then for each pop it takes n which is the size of the list.

for example, you have a list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] here n = 9
let's say you want to remove 3 so to find 3 it takes 3 units of time and then we need to shift the elements after 3 it takes 6 units so in total 9 units of time.

So if you are popping n/2 elements it takes O(n) for each element. as the last element takes n/2 in big O notation we say it as O(n).

So for n/2 elements, it will take O(n^2).